# Given a list of indices, combine columns

Tags: javascript, node.js

say I have a list of indices, where no index is greater than N-1:

```
const indices = [0,4,8,22];
```

and given a matrix A of MxN, is there shorthand to combine the columns into a smaller matrix, this is how I would do it:

```
const matrixSubset = indices.reduce((a,b) => {
      a[b] = A[b];
      return a;
},[]);
```

to do it without iteration, would be:

```
const a = [A[0],A[4],A[8],A[22]];
```

Comment: this function http://stackoverflow.com/a/966938/975097

Comment: `a.push(A[b])` ??

Comment: Wouldn’t that just be a [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)? `const a = indices.map((index) => A[index])`.

Comment: Yes map would work fine I think, except it would need to be `[...indices.map((i) => A[i])` but yeah that should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably be as simple/concise as it gets:

```
const a = indices.map(i => A[i])
```

Comment: Why do you need the `[...]` instead of just `const a = indices.map(i => A[i])`?

Comment: because it's going in a surrounding matrix MxN, that's why I posed the question to see if there was any other way...see latter half of OP...nvm I think you are right